# Throwing NotImplementedException on default case in switch statement

Tags: c#, exception, switch-statement

Should I throw a `NotImplementedException()` on `default`, if I have cases for all possible enum types?

Comment: I guess it would depend on your app and what would happen if you ended up with a value out of range.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for a value that *must*, by definition, correspond to the value of an enumeration, and you've received something else, that's definitely an invalid argument.

But now you have to consider the context.

Is the method private, and only accessible by members of your class library or application? If it is, it's a coding error that shouldn't EVER occur in the first place. Assert and fail.

If, on the other hand, it's a public or protected method, and can be accessed by clients consuming your library, you should definitely throw with a meaningful message (and preferably a well-known exception type).

It's important to remember that enumerations are not range-checked in the Framework. I may specify that a method requires a parameter of type Environment.SpecialFolder; but it will accept *any* 32-bit integer value.

So, in short, if your method is for public consumption, *yes, by all means, throw.* If it's not for public consumption, [Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx).

Comment: +1 well said. If the unexpected value comes from your own, Assert and fail.  On the other hand, if it comes from someone else using your code then you should throw an exception and give the calling code a chance to recover.

Comment: Why is Assert better than throwing ? Maybe that condition is a rare case and the developer does not hit it, and it is hit only by the tester, who uses the Release build (with no Assert compiled in) and the error gets swallowed. Is it better to swallow the errors, don't crash but do a hard to debug incorrect thing, instead of crashing with a stack trace ?

Comment: Another question is how much error checking is worth to put in code, if you don't write API's for other companies ? Short code is I think more readable than code in which each method size is doubled because of error checking. Isn't it ?

Comment: @csuporj - In regards to your first question, if you're that worried about really obscure bugs, use Fail instead. A bug that is that obscure is going to slip through anyways. One can hope to mitigate those circumstances with thorough unit tests and up front QA tests, but *there is no such thing as modern bug free software.*

Comment: @csuporj - Regarding your second question, Error checking and the default case in a switch structure are not exactly the same thing. He's got to do something specific based on what the value of the enumeration is. If it's not one of the enumeration's *known* values, what should he do? The caller is going to expect *something.* And if the parameter type specifies an enumeration value, anything other than that is a violation of the method's contract. Failure to ensure that leads to your first question.

Answer (score 10):

It really depends.

- The [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) is something like todo mark for me. It means that somebody will comes later to finish the code. However I don't think that's case of default case which shouldn't happen.
- When you are checking state of the object you may consider [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx). Your method is designed only to work with existing cases.
- When you are discriminating over input parameter [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) is always appropriate.
- In other cases I prefer [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx). It slightly indicates that something is wrong with platform or version. And the incompatible versions of the code is the true root of the problem when default case of switch which shouldn't happen happened.

Comment: interesting answer. what is your motivation / reasoning?

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for updating. I agree completely with you what how you've put it. That's helped me get it straight in my own head.

Comment: If its a public method you are calling directly, use either InvalidEnumArgumentException or ArgumentOutOfRangeException. If its a member implicitly called as part of an object instance, use InvalidOperationException with details about why it was thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not NotImplementedException, but ArgumentException. It would really depend on where you're using it.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a reasonable option.

Personally, I would create a new type of exception (perhaps an `InvalidEnumException` or give it another name that will make sense to the support team) and throw that.

Comment: I'd personally try and reuse one of the myriad of existing exception types.  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/20/custom-exceptions-when-should-you-create-them.aspx

Comment: Agreed, downvoted because I don't think this is a case for a custom exception type.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the specific process, but yes, it's good process to respond in the default: case if something wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd throw `ApplicationException` because if your code reaches default and you didn't expected it this means that something in your code is not behaving as you where thinking.

Comment: Isn't the use of ApplicationException frowned upon?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case. It will be helpful if you throw an exception during the early days of integration. The users of your library can immediately come to know the errors

Answer (score 0):

I'd say at least you should put a `Debug.Fail()` there.

You should throw an exception in case if the method in no way can proceed. But if you are like converting your enum values to string representations, then you can just return some warning string instead. The product will not crash on users due to an obvious mistake, there will be probably a workaround, and everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you threw the exception what would happen?  In what context is the switch statement being executed?  Should that situation ever happen?  Should it ever happen at run-time in production code?  Do your unit tests cover this situation?  If so, perhaps an assert would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You should first consider what it would mean if you got a value outside of the known cases- what does the variable being switched on represent? Then you might simply use an exception type that fits what is actually happening.